# how to use group by function in the condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

my inner query is working well but when i use group by function i am getting an error `"Column 'b.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."` 
i have used multiple tricks but none of them is working(like distinct)

```
select * from (
        SELECT  tsr.id,tblstckid,ts.articleNo,ts.code,size,ts.insertDate  FROM [tbl_setsRegister] tsr
APPLY dbo.Split1(tsr.tblstckid, ',') AS htvf 
        inner join tbl_stock ts on ts.id=htvf.Item where ts.id not in(60,62) and ts.articleNo='121010' and code='unknown-1')
group by b.tblstckid
```

what i want is to get distinct values from tblstckid with other columns also

sample data

```
id  tblstckid   articleNo   cCode   size    insertDate
21  55,56,58,   121010  unknown-1   34  2018-09-20 19:44:00.000
21  55,56,58,   121010  unknown-1   36  2018-09-20 19:44:00.000
21  55,56,58,   121010  unknown-1   38  2018-09-20 19:44:00.000
22  57,         121010  unknown-1   36  2018-09-20 19:44:00.000
23  59,61,63,   121010  unknown-1   34  2018-09-20 19:46:00.000
23  59,61,63,   121010  unknown-1   36  2018-09-20 19:46:00.000
```

i want get rid of duplicate tblstckid

Comment: Sample data and desired results.  Your query is simply not correct, `select *`/`group by`.  No aggregation functions.  Incomplete subquery.

Comment: i just want to get rid of duplicate tblstckid and want other columns

Answer (score 3):

You must put all the columns of the SELECT-list into GROUP BY except aggregation columns. As you select all but put only one column in GROUP BY, it throws an error

```
SELECT b.tblstckid
FROM (
    SELECT tsr.id, tblstckid, ts.articleNo, ts.code, size, ts.insertDate
    FROM [tbl_setsRegister] tsr
    APPLY dbo.Split1(tsr.tblstckid, ',') AS htvf 
    INNER JOIN tbl_stock ts
        ON ts.id = htvf.Item
    WHERE ts.id NOT IN(60,62) AND ts.articleNo = '121010' AND code = 'unknown-1'
) b
GROUP BY b.tblstckid
```

However, as you have not any aggregate function, but you used GROUP BY  that is confusing

you can use `row_number`

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT tsr.id, tblstckid, ts.articleNo, ts.code, size, ts.insertDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY tsr.id, tblstckid, ts.articleNo, ts.code, ts.insertDate
            ORDER BY size
        ) AS rn
    FROM [tbl_setsRegister] tsr
    APPLY dbo.Split1(tsr.tblstckid, ',') AS htvf 
    INNER JOIN tbl_stock ts
        ON ts.id = htvf.Item
    WHERE ts.id NOT IN(60,62) AND ts.articleNo = '121010' AND code = 'unknown-1'
) b
WHERE b.rn=1
```

Comment: this is not giving me other columns

Comment: @sam5808 you can use row_number() function i post another answer

Answer (score 0):

You must apply an aggregate function to all the columns not in the GROUP BY clause. A possible solution is:

```
SELECT
    id, tblstckid, articleNo, code,
    SUM(size) AS tot_size, MAX(ts.insertDate) AS lastInsertDate
FROM (
    SELECT tsr.id, tblstckid, ts.articleNo, ts.code, size, ts.insertDate
    FROM [tbl_setsRegister] tsr
    APPLY dbo.Split1(tsr.tblstckid, ',') AS htvf 
    INNER JOIN tbl_stock ts
        ON ts.id = htvf.Item
    WHERE ts.id NOT IN(60,62) AND ts.articleNo = '121010' AND code = 'unknown-1'
) b
GROUP BY id, tblstckid, articleNo, code
```

You must decide which aggregate function makes most sense. If you want to keep all values, you can also use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
 STRING_AGG (CAST(size AS varchar(10), ', ') AS sizes
```